# Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nib

After i try to make segue from login page to Tabbar controller,
my app doesn't run anymore

the warning is below.

```
2016-06-01 18:15:49.255 noonting[62702:982483] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/HK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F801E079-1231-47D6-B108-0644D7F82931/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/48A07480-11CA-4140-AA53-A405473635C3/noonting.app> (loaded)' with name 'Home' and directory 'Main.storyboardc''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e6b4d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110458deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e6b4cbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010f2a4c89 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 499
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010f61f314 -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010f61f467 -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] + 69
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010eedc89f -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 94
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010eedcbcf -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010eedb3ef -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1392
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010eed8714 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    10  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001123138c8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    11  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000112313741 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 178
    12  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000112313aca -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e5da301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e5d022c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e5cf6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e5cf0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010eed7f21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010eedcf09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  noonting                            0x000000010e0f7be2 main + 114
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110f2592d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My first try code is below. "Home" is identifier of Tabbar Controller

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Home", sender: nil)

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate

let initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") //as! UIViewController
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Part of my second try code is below:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
let tabBarController: UITabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as! UITabBarController
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you made segue between pages? Did you set segue `identifier` to "Home"? If so, left only one line of code, and it will work

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Home", sender: nil)
```

On other hand, if you did set your Tabbar controller identifier (since you use storyboard, this is `Storyboard ID` field in Identity inspector of Tabbar controller) to "Home", you may use this code:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate

let initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") //as! UIViewController
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Your logs says me that you didn't set this identifier. Don't mix it up with segue identifier, this is different things and you prefer use different strings for them.